# Java - FilenotfoundException for reading text file

Tags: java, file, text, path, filenotfoundexception

by running this...

```
File file = new File("Highscores.scr");
```

i keep getting this error, and i really don't know how to get around it. 
the file is currently sitting in my source packages with my .java files.
I can quite easily read the file by specifying the path but i intend to run this on multiple computers so i need the file to be portable with the program.
this question isnt about reading the text file but rather specifying its location without using an absolute path .
ive searched for the answer but the answers i get are just "specify the name" and "specify the absolute path".
id post an image to make it more clear but i dont have the 10 rep to do so :/
how do i do this?

cheers.

Comment: In which directory is your class located?

Comment: Try `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())` to see if this is the correct directory.

Comment: no problem post the image some body will edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to put it in your classpath then [getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        new Sandbox().run();
    }

    private void run() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        URL resource = Sandbox.class.getResource("/my.txt");
        File file = new File(resource.toURI());
        String s = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
        System.out.println(s);
    }


}
```

I'm doing this because I'm assuming you need a `File`.  But if you have an api which takes an `InputStream` instead, it's probably better to use `getResourceAsStream` instead.

Notice the path, `/my.txt`.  That means, "get a file named my.txt that is in the root directory of the classpath".  I'm sure you can read more about `getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` to learn more about how to do this.  But the key thing here is that **the classpath for the file will be the same for any computer you give the executable** to (as long as you don't move the file around in your classpath).

BTW, if you get a null pointer exception on the line that does `new File`, that means that you haven't specified the correct classpath for the file.

Comment: used

InputStream file = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Highscores.scr");

it worked beautifully!
THANKS tieTYT!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember the default directory with be the same as your project folder level. Put the file one level higher.

```
-Project/
 ----src/
 ----test/
-Highscores.scr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your code on your eclipse then you need to put your `Highscores.scr` to your project folder. Try that and check.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run the following sample program to check which is the current directory your program is picking up.

```
File f = new File(".");
System.out.println("Current Directory is: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
```